# Get latest_partition_timestamp in dbt

Tags: sql, dbt

I've been trying to debug this but I can't understand why the error is popping up.
So I wrote the macro to get the latest partition as

```
{% macro latest_partition() %}
    {%- call statement('latest_partition_query', True) -%}
        SELECT TIMESTAMP_TRUNC(MAX(event_timestamp), DAY) AS latest_partition FROM {{ this }}
    {%- endcall -%}
    {%- set max_timestamp = load_result('latest_partition_query')['data'] -%}
    {%- do return(max_timestamp) -%}
{% endmacro %}
```

This is giving the value of max_timestamp as [(datetime.datetime(2022, 10, 26, 0, 0, tzinfo=datetime.timezone.utc),)] but when I'm trying to index it to get the timestamp using indices [0][0] it gives an error 'None' has no attribute 'data' .
Not sure how adding index is making it None

The expected result would be just the datetime.datetime(2022, 10, 26, 0, 0, tzinfo=datetime.timezone.utc) part

Answer (score 1):

Add an if_execute block to it

```
{% macro latest_partition() %}
    {%- call statement('latest_partition_query', True) -%}
        SELECT TIMESTAMP_TRUNC(MAX(event_timestamp), DAY) AS latest_partition FROM {{ this }}
    {%- endcall -%}
    {%- set results = load_result('latest_partition_query')-%}
    {% if execute %}
        {% set max_timestamp = results.data[0][0] %}
    {% else %}
        {% set max_timestamp = None %}
    {% endif %}
    {%do return(max_timestamp) %}
{% endmacro %}
```

Comment: A link to the docs, so that you also understand the why of the `{% if execute %}` clause: https://docs.getdbt.com/reference/dbt-jinja-functions/execute